# Why does Cannot Find Module Error occur if .js file extension is missing?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have a simple Svelte project that runs a module function, which was installed with npm. When I run it though, I get this error: `Cannot find module 'C:\...\practice2\node_modules\jsxgraph\src\jxg' imported from C:\...\practice2\node_modules\jsxgraph\src\index.js`, which involves this line of code in the `index.js`: `import JXG from "./jxg";`. I tried some troubleshooting, and when I added the `.js` suffix, ie `import JXG from "./jxg.js";` the error message didn't appear for that specific import. The package has many imports, and I'm not sure that applying find and replace for every import statement in the package is the best solution. Is there some other way to fix the error?

I tried [Node can't find modules without .js extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242186/node-cant-find-modules-without-js-extension) but it doesn't seem to work with `npm run dev`, which is how I'm running the code.

I also tried [Can't import module without the .js extension in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928008/cant-import-module-without-the-js-extension-in-nodejs), but this comments more on general practice within someone's project and not how to fix the problem when it exists in general.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to the way Node.js resolves module imports and the absence of file extensions in the import statements. When you use import JXG from "./jxg";, Node.js will look for a file named jxg without any extension, and it might not find it, leading to the "Cannot find module" error.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. Add "type": "module" to your package.json
   In your package.json file, add the following line:

{
"type": "module"
}

This tells Node.js that your project uses ECMAScript modules (ESM). With this setting, you can use file extensions in your import statements, and Node.js will recognize them. After making this change, you should be able to use:

import JXG from "./jxg";

2. Rename index.js to index.mjs
   If you don't want to modify your package.json, you can rename the index.js file to index.mjs. This extension indicates that the file is an ECMAScript module, and Node.js will recognize it as such.
3. Add file extensions to imports
   As you mentioned, you can add file extensions to all your import statements:

import JXG from "./jxg.js";

If modifying every import statement is cumbersome, you might consider using a tool like find and replace to automate the process.

Choose the approach that best fits your project structure and preferences. Keep in mind that Node.js is moving towards ESM (ECMAScript modules), so specifying file extensions in your imports might become more common practice.

Comment: I've already applied the first solution and it doesn't work. The second solution is a cumbersome workaround just like using "find and replace" because the error appears in a different file if I change all of the import statements in index.js, i.e. I would need to apply the change to every file with an import. I just think that there should be a way to import a module without doing massive changes to it.

Comment: you can Update your Configuration (for Webpack or similar bundlers):

If you're using a bundler like Webpack, you might need to update its configuration to allow the omission of file extensions. Ensure that your bundler is set up to resolve modules without extensions. In a webpack configuration file, you can add the following to the resolve object:

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js']
}

if above method is don't work then you can use automated find and replace operation on the package's source code that you already mention(best choice).  This can be automated using tools like 'sed'

Comment: However, be cautious with this approach to avoid unintended consequences.

find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec sed -i 's|from "jsxgraph/src/|from "jsxgraph/src/|g' {} +

This command finds all .js files in your project and replaces the import paths. Adjust the path in the sed command as needed.